# I want to make a search bar for this code to search by buttons (between btn1 and btn2 and btn3) and hide the non-matched results

Tags: java, android, android-studio, search

I am trying to add a search bar that enables me to search by buttons, search between btn1 and btn2 and btn3. I tried a lot of codes but all of them were focused on TextView and not on buttons. So hope to help me and if I missed details please let me know to describe more.

The two files (.java and .xml) are typed below. thank you.

**file.java**

```
package com.example.myapp1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView sv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My First App");



        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});


        Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});

        Button btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity4.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});



        List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();

  
        buttonList.add(view.findViewById(R.id.btn1));
        buttonList.add(view.findViewById(R.id.btn2));
        buttonList.add(view.findViewById(R.id.btn3));

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {

                    String buttonText = (String) buttonList.get(i).getText();

                    if(buttonText.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
                        buttonList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        buttonList.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if(s.isEmpty()) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
                        buttonList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Absolute Pressure" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Acoustic Flowmeter" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Bernoulli Number" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by search by buttons? Are you looking to search the text that is held within the button?

Here is a way you can go about this:

1. Make a list that contains all the instances of your buttons.
   List(findViewById(R.id.btn1), etc)

   ```
    List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();

    buttonList.add(view.findViewById(R.id.button_search1));
    buttonList.add(view.findViewById(R.id.button_search2));
    buttonList.add(view.findViewById(R.id.button_search3));
   ```
2. We are going to use the listeners available to the search view to do the work.

   ```
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        // You can use this for when the submit is clicked
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            // We loop over the button list
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {

                // We get the text of the button
                String buttonText = (String) buttonList.get(i).getText();

                // We turn both the button text and search result to lowercase
                // So that results are not case sensitive

                // If they match
                if(buttonText.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
                    // We make button visible
                    buttonList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    // If it doesn't, we make invisible
                    buttonList.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        // You can use this when the text is changing.
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            // If text is empty, reset results
            if(s.isEmpty()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
                    buttonList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes exactly, so when I search for example about absolute pressure, which is btn1, I need only this button stays and the other buttons disappear.

Comment: I did another project with a list view and it runned successfully, but I need a search for an activity contains buttons and not listview. Hope to help

Comment: I have updated answer with some steps on how to achieve a solution to your problem :)

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you so much, but I am not expert enough to transfer these steps to a code. So if you have a similar complete code with these steps I will be very grateful to you :)

Comment: Can you please help me with that if you don't mind. I need it as a code since I am a beginner and I don't know how to convert these steps into a code. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer with code, however, I would suggest you learn about arrays and array lists as well as listeners to fully understand what is happening in the code. Hopefully this helps start you off, best of luck :)

Comment: Oh also, I would also suggest you start learning Kotlin instead of Java, as it is very rare for companies to be using Java unless they are using a legacy (old) codebase. It is also lighter on syntax than Java is, making it easier to learn!

Comment: Hey CodeGorilla, I appreciate your hard work and your advices. thank you so much. I added your code to my code and there is no errors thanks to you :) but the app didn't open since there is something wrong with the code. To make sure, the code has no error but something went wrong I don't know why the app didn't open. I have edited the new code above and hope to help me with that last thing only :) Thank you so much for your time

Comment: The code you have pasted is using "findViewById([resource name here])". You do not have any resources in your layout for search view, or the 3 buttons I added. Also you set your view to null - please try using the errors you are receiving before replying, otherwise I am just solving the problem for you. Programming requires some thinking my friend :P

Comment: Just so it is clear: you need to add the required search view and buttons to your layout file and give them the names you wish to find in the java class -> @+id/btn2 is like R.id.btn2